# Tensorflow: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Sequential' and 'Sequential'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am following a [Siamese Network](https://medium.com/predict/face-recognition-from-scratch-using-siamese-networks-and-tensorflow-df03e32f8cd0) tutorial to build a face recognition model with tensorflow

```py
def build_net(img_shape):
    """
    :type img_shape: tuple. Shape of input image. Here is(1,height, width). 1 because pgm file only has one channel.
    :rtype:tensorflow Sequential
    """
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # convolution layer 1
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = "relu", input_shape = img_shape, data_format = "channels_first"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
    # convolution layer 2
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    # deep face mentioned that there are 67 points to detect on a human face, so use 70 features.
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation='relu'))
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

And define a `dist` to count the distance between two output vectors.

```py
im1_features = build_net(input_dim)
im2_features = build_net(input_dim)
dist = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda tensors: tf.keras.backend.abs[tensors[0] - tensors[1]])([im1_features, im2_features])
```

Error happend in `dist`

```
  File "e:\School\AIAS\proj\build_model.py", line 102, in <lambda>
    dist = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda tensors: tf.keras.backend.abs[tensors[0] - tensors[1]])([im1_features, im2_features])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Sequential' and 'Sequential'
```

How can I make function `build_net` return vectors rather than a Sequential object?

### update

I changed the code into:

```
def build_net(img_shape):
    """
    :type img_shape: tuple. Shape of input image. Here is(1,height, width). 1 because pgm file only has one channel.
    :rtype:tensorflow Sequential
    """
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    # convolution layer 1
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = "relu", input_shape = img_shape, data_format = "channels_first"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
    # convolution layer 2
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    # deep face mentioned that there are 67 points to detect on a human face, so use 70 features.
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation='relu'))
    img = tf.keras.Input(shape = img_shape)
    res = model(img)
    return res
```

now it returns this stuff
[image]

The error become:
`function' object is not subscriptable`

I still cannot find the vector

Comment: You can get the `.output` property of the created models to get the tensor at the output.

Comment: @jdehesa I edited this question. Now the return type is the exactly the same with .output, but it got a new error: function' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `tf.keras.abs` like this:

```
tf.keras.backend.abs(
    x
)
```

Not

```
tf.keras.backend.abs[
    x
]
```

It's a function, not an array.
Did this solve your problem?